# Поиск в ширину или поиск в глубину

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Надо обойти все вершины графа в любом порядке. Что лучше использовать: поиск в ширину или в глубину? Какие преимущества и недостатки у алгоритмов в принципе?

Comment: @Unick и что лучше?

Comment: @user247920 ну это же зависит от задачи, которую вы хотите решить.

Comment: @Flowneee разве я не написал свою задачу?

Comment: @user247920 это очень общая задача. В таком виде можно вполне главу какого-нибудь учебника по алгоритмам написать. Какой формы граф? Какие ограничения по памяти, времени? Это как минимум те вопросы, на которые придется ответить, чтобы выбрать "эффективный" алгоритм. Если задача просто обойти все вершины, без каких-либо условий, то берите любой из алгоритмов. Я бы взял поиск в глубину, он, как мне кажется проще, там сложнее ошибиться.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Отвечаю на конкретный вопрос конкретным ответом - про один способ я скажу "рекурсивненько", а про второй - ....нерекурсивненько. И Вам абсолютно правильно заметили про задачу - имеется ввиду прикладная задача, к который Вы хотите применить один из этих алгоритмов.

Comment: 1) "про один способ я скажу "рекурсивненько", а про второй - ....нерекурсивненько" - не понятно, что вы этим хотели сказать; 2) прикладная задача - обойти все вершины графа в любом порядке, что написано в вопросе

Comment: Поиск в глубину - классическая реализация данного алгоритма имеет рекрсивную форму.

Comment: А что касается "эффективности" - для Вашей задачи - кажется, не имеет смысла делать выбор. Берите любой.